# Script to open URL only on first Friday of the month and between 8am-10am

Tags: javascript, date, url, time

I'm working in Virtual Tour Software with Javascript and want to make an action, which will open an URL (with photo panorama) ONLY in particular part of time (in that case it's first Friday of month and only between 8am and 10am). Any ideas? Thanks Michal

For now I got somethink like this:

```
var startDate = new Date('Jun 5, 2020 8:00:00').getTime();
var endDate = new Date('Jun 5, 2020 10:00:00').getTime();

setInterval(function() {
var now = new Date().getTime();
var visible = now > startDate && now < endDate;
var hotspot = this.getPanoramaOverlayByName(this.getMediaByName('Panorama'), 'Hotspot');
if(hotspot && hotspot.get('enabled') != visible)
hotspot.set('enabled', visible);
}.bind(this), 1000);`
```

The problem is that I need to change "var start" and "var end" every time. I want to make it visible on every First Friday of month.

Comment: Please post what you've tried. We're here to help you with code you've written, not write it for you. The first day of the month is given by `let d = new Date(); d.setDate(1)`. The first Friday can be found by applying the day number returned from `d.getDay()` to the date.

Comment: Thanks Rob for an answer. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getday() and getdate() function in js to find the day which is friday and date which is less or equal to 7 whatever the month and year is.
you can add following in your code like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var startDate = d.getDate(); // this will gives you only date 
var isFriday = d.getDay();   // this will gives index of the day
var n = d.getHours();         // add this new line gethours
if((startDate <= 7 && isFriday == 5) && (n >= 8 && n <= 10)) // as indexing 5 for friday
{
   setInterval(function() {
   var hotspot = this.getPanoramaOverlayByName(this.getMediaByName('Panorama'), 'Hotspot');
   if(hotspot && hotspot.get('enabled') != true)
   hotspot.set('enabled', true);
   }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It might work but what about active hours and fact that it should be only first Friday of month?

Comment: replace this with condition
var n = d.getHours();
if((startDate <= 7 && isFriday == 5) &&(n >=8 && n <= 10))
this will help you